# Sending JSON obj fields in Insomnia

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express

I'm trying to send a JSON object inside one of the fields I have, in order to store it in the MongoDB (Using Mongoose Schema). Right now I'm facing a server-sided JSON parsing error.

This is what I'm trying to send

```
{
"text":"N1y",
"localId":"123",
"type": "media",
"attachments": {
url:"Test.jpg",
publicId:"123"
}
}
```

My Moongose Schema

```
const messageSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  createdAt: {
    type: String,
    default: new Date()
  },
  chatId: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  localId: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  text: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  authorId: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  type: {
    type: String,
    default: 'text'
  },
  attachments: {},
  style: {
    type: String,
    default: 'normal'
  }
```

Using Node.JS with Express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the schema update attachments type to object and request object in not correct json.

{
    "text": "N1y",
    "localId": "123",
    "type": "media",
    "attachments": {
        **"url"**: "Test.jpg",
        **"publicId"**: "123"
    }
}

**Schema**

```
attachments: {
  type : Object
},
```

**OR**

```
attachments: {
    url: {
        type: String
    },
    publicId: {
        type: String
    },
}
```

Comment: But if I were to have an array of urls and public ids, how would I go about that? Simply?  "url": ["Test.jpg", "Test2.png"], "publicId": ["123","525"] }

Comment: you can try `url: [String]` inside attachments.